# How to convert a column in a dataframe to an index datetime object?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question about how to convert a column 'Timestamp' into an index&datetime. And then also drop the column once it's converted into an index.

```
df = {'Timestamp':['20/01/2021 01:00:00.12 AM','20/01/2021 01:00:00.21 AM','20/01/2021 01:00:01.34 AM], 
      'Value':['14','178','158','75']}
```

I tried the following, but obvious didn't work.

```
df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp.str[0])
df=df.set_index(['Timestamp'], drop=True)
```

FYI. The df is actually a lot text processing so unfortunately I cannot just do read_csv and parse datetime object. :( So yes, the df is exactly as what's prescribed above.

Thank you.

Comment: What didn't that work?  Was it an error?  Did the column parse correctly?

Comment: It just gives me error. So I changed the code to df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp) only, and it works. However, it gives me only dd-mm-yyyy... it's now missing the hh:mm:ss.sss. It also takes so long?...

Answer (score 1):

Don't enclose 'Timestamp' in square brackets.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp':['20/01/2021 01:00:00.12 AM','20/01/2021 01:00:00.21 AM','20/01/2021 01:00:01.34 AM'], 
      'Value':['14','178','158']})

df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])

df = df.set_index('Timestamp')
  
print(df)

## Output

                          Value
Timestamp
20/01/2021 01:00:00.12 AM    14
20/01/2021 01:00:00.21 AM   178
20/01/2021 01:00:01.34 AM   158
```